# AlarmManager not working in Fragment nor in Main.java

Tags: android, android-fragments, alarmmanager

I HAVE to be missing something, I made a test Application Project for myself and this works perfectly there but when I tried to implement my `AlarmManager` into my main project's fragment it just won't work. Here's my code:

The Method that is in my fragment:

```
public void schedule()
{
    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10*1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


}
```

and here is my `AlarmReceiver.class`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

And also here are the preparations in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

   <application
    ... >
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: It seems that it doesn't even reach the `AlarmReceiver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work.
But it the problem is the manifest. the

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
```

should be the with the full package name, for example

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

I've double check it with my app. so you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. how did u solve it ? the same way i suggested ?
i've got disagreement with a buddy of mine...

Comment: yes exactly! I had to add "com.example..." since the fragment I am trying to use and the AlarmReceiver were not in the same package

Answer (score 2):

You are using the receiver incorrectly. What you need to do first is to add an action to your receiver's manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.action.ALARM" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, construct the intent with that action:

```
public void schedule() {
Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.action.ALARM");

...

}
```

and in your receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals("com.example.action.ALARM")
  Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This should do the trick.